# "TypeError: Singleton array cannot be considered a valid collection" using sklearn train_test_split

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

TypeError: Singleton array array(0.2) cannot be considered a valid collection.

```
X = df.iloc[:, [1,7]].values
y= df.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 0.2)
```

I am getting this error when trying to train_test_split. I am able to train my model with X and y values. However, i would like to split my dataframe and then train and test it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please paste in some sample input of how the `df` looks like? Just copy paste the output of `df.head()` and format as code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A not-so-commonly known fact is that [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) can split any number of arrays, not just two ("train", and "test"). See the linked docs and the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2073) for more info.

For example,

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
y = df1.pop('C')
z = df1.pop('D')
X = df1

splits = train_test_split(X, y, z, test_size=0.2)
len(splits)
# 6
```

IOW, the only way to specify the test size is by specifying the keyword argument `test_size`. All positional arguments are assumed to be collections that are to be split, and in your case, since you do

```
train_test_split(X, y, 0.2)
```

The function tries to split `0.2`, but since a float is not a collection, the error is raised. The solution is to (as mentioned), specify the keyword argument:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I have been stuck here for past two hours. Need one more clarification. What will happen if my dataset has only a single row of value?

Comment: @JohnSamuel One split will be empty, and the other split will have the same, single row. Hope that answers it.

Comment: @JohnSamuel More precisely, train split will be empty and test split will get that single row in the current implementation. There [is an ongoing discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11028) as to what should be the default behaviour for this case.