# Singleton array cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I want to perform hyperparameter tuning for Kernel PCA. My code raised `Singleton array cannot be considered a valid collection` error during `train_test_split`.

Someone asked a similar question (["TypeError: Singleton array cannot be considered a valid collection" using sklearn train_test_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800369/typeerror-singleton-array-cannot-be-considered-a-valid-collection-using-sklea)) but the answer is not applicable here because I still get an error after specifying `test_size`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X = meth_clin_sub_nt_2_kipan.iloc[:,7:-1]
y_type = meth_clin_sub_nt_2_kipan["type"]

# Color by meth_clin_sub_nt_2_kipan["type"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_kpca, y_type, test_size=0.3, random_state=30)

## Kernel PCA
kpca = KernelPCA()
kpca.fit(X_train, y_train)

## Parameters
param_grid = {'n_components': list(range(1,9)), 'kernel': ('linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid', 'cosine', 'precomputed'), 'degree': list(range(1,9)), 'tol': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], 'fit_inverse_transform': (bool, False), 'eigen_solver': ('auto', 'dense', 'arpack', 'randomized'), 'alpha': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]}

gs = GridSearchCV(X_kpca, param_grid, cv=10)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_16/3046291160.py in <module>
      1 # Color by meth_clin_sub_nt_2_kipan["type"]
----> 2 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_kpca, y_type, test_size=0.3)
      3 
      4 ## Kernel PCA
      5 kpca = KernelPCA()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(test_size, train_size, random_state, shuffle, stratify, *arrays)
   2415         raise ValueError("At least one array required as input")
   2416 
-> 2417     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2418 
   2419     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    376 
    377     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 378     check_consistent_length(*result)
    379     return result
    380 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    327     """
    328 
--> 329     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    327     """
    328 
--> 329     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    268         if len(x.shape) == 0:
    269             raise TypeError(
--> 270                 "Singleton array %r cannot be considered a valid collection." % x
    271             )
    272         # Check that shape is returning an integer or default to len

TypeError: Singleton array array(KernelPCA(gamma=15, kernel='rbf', n_components=2, random_state=42),
      dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Sample data:

```
`meth_clin_sub_nt_2_kipan.iloc[0:3,-10:].to_dict()`
{'cg09560533': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.900095504652308,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.81104132439858,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.457870839535175},
 'cg09560549': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.731219716727976,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.816886151477418,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.804368893288968},
 'cg09560590': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.331126978536942,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.606999048224196,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.638951186043284},
 'cg09560599': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.0166606663293514,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.0304682590716158,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.0188827320665545},
 'cg09560658': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.92977749464931,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.684140609221568,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.934064932323703},
 'cg09560763': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.821841061291043,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.287309064005432,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.393975491255026},
 'cg09560811': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.927202214991965,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.932595863242732,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.949126686353227},
 'cg09560911': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.018890114367182,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.0182049878300791,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.0272930258041942},
 'cg09560953': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.844136240512521,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.253988367060448,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.898586638943748},
 'type': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 'kirp'}}
```